# How to return the name of a Worksheet in a cell with a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, worksheet

How can I return the name of a Worksheet, in a Cell of another Worksheet, using an Excel formula? (not using VBA)

Comment: You would need to know the name of the worksheet before you can retrieve it as it is not the same (default) worksheet. While this would change if renamed, I fail to see any real-world purpose.

Comment: I want the name of a Worksheet, returns in a cell.

Comment: To return all the sheet names only use Excel formulas, you can refer to my other post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46470875/4388883).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula to return the name of the *current* sheet.

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)
```

This formula can be slightly modified to return the name of any sheet in the workbook, e.g. to return "Sheet2":

```
=MID(CELL("filename",Sheet2!A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",Sheet2!A1))+1,255)
```

Only condition: The excel spreadsheet must be saved somewhere on your computer first. (i.e. you cannot simply open a blank sheet and type in this formula before saving it - the formula will not work unless the spreadsheet is saved.)

Comment: As per my comment above, `A1` is insufficient since OP wishes *'the name of a Worksheet, in a Cell of another Worksheets'*. It would have to be Sheet1!A1 when put into a cell on Sheet2.

Comment: Ah, good point. Yes this formula will only return the name of the current sheet. Not sure if it is possible to return the name of another sheet in the same workbook, (not without a helper cell on each sheet anyway).

Comment: However, if Sheet1!A1 was given a defined name with workbook scope, the defined name could be used in the formula.

Comment: @Jeeped, of course, `=MID(CELL("filename",Sheet1!A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",Sheet1!A1))+1,255)` is extend of this. Seems the there were a reference in [ExtendOffice](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2618-excel-reference-tab-name.html)