# EXCEL : Is there a formula based method to create a cell's value based on the sheet tab

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Looking for a way to have the Sheet tab name be referenced in a specific cell on that sheet. Tab name say is "XYZ", I'd like cell B2 to display that name. I have found the following command that does this, however the name seems to change across the workbook based on the last tab name that had been modified:

```
=MID(CELL("filename"),FIND("]",CELL("filename"))+1,255)
```

Has anyone had any success with doing something similar to this?

Thanks!

Comment: add the cell reference: `=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)`

Comment: Take a look of my post here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46470875/4388883) to list out all the sheet names in a workbook.

Answer (score 1):

I use a similar formula to yours, but reference cell A1 in the formula:

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)
```

I haven't had any problems doing it this way since I started using it.

Comment: Just realized my answer is the same as @ScottCraner's comment. Must have gotten it from the same place. I've been using this formula for several months, with no issues getting the tab name.